# How to get the nth parameter of a list with delimiter space in python

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Newbie python learner around here...

What I´m trying to achieve is read the lines from an iptables log file, get the parameter that match "SRC=", delete the string "SRC=" and print out unique IPs.
In Bash it is pretty straightforward with awk and so on. 
I read about comprehension lists and re.function and dig into examples, but with no success. Any tips for lists/objects/strings manipulations are welcome.

code:

```
import sys
import os
import re


with open("iptables.log","r") as f:
content = f.readlines()

print (type (content))
content = [l.replace('SRC=','') for l in content]

print (len(content))
print " ".join(content)

f.close()
```

the log:

```
Sep  1 09:27:46 hostname kernel: IPTables-Dropped: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00000 SRC=255.255.255.1 DST=10.0.0.1 LEN=56 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=10 ID=36829 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=490000 DPT=80 WINDOW=15500 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 MARK=0x32
Sep  1 09:27:47 hostname kernel: IPTables-Dropped: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00000 SRC=255.255.255.1 DST=10.0.0.1 LEN=56 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=10 ID=36830 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=490000 DPT=80 WINDOW=15500 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 MARK=0x32
Sep  1 09:27:47 hostname kernel: IPTables-Dropped: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00000 SRC=255.255.255.1 DST=10.0.0.1 LEN=56 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=10 ID=36830 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=490000 DPT=80 WINDOW=15500 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 MARK=0x32
Sep  1 09:27:47 hostname kernel: IPTables-Dropped: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00000 SRC=255.255.255.2 DST=10.0.0.1 LEN=56 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=10 ID=36830 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=490000 DPT=80 WINDOW=15500 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 MARK=0x32
```

The print should be:

```
255.255.255.1
255.255.255.2
```

How can I get the nth parameter with delimiter " " (space) in python?

Comment: you could use `split` to return a list and then an index to extract the parameter you want

Comment: I'm slightly surprised you've found `str.replace` and `str.join`, but not `str.split`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to split the elements by white-space and then get the 10th element from it (which would be the element with `SRC=`) . And then replace the `SRC=` in that, or you can simply take the substring (removing the first four characters which would be `'SRE='` , by using the subscript `[4:]`).

Also, if you want just the unique elements, you can use set comprehension in Python 2.7 + .

Example -

```
lstset = {l.split()[9].replace('SRC=','') for l in content}
print('\n'.join(lstset))
```

Demo -

```
>>> content = """Sep  1 09:27:46 hostname kernel: IPTables-Dropped: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00000 SRC=255.255.255.1 DST=10.0.0.1 LEN=56 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=10 ID=36829 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=490000 DPT=80 WINDOW=15500 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 MARK=0x32
... Sep  1 09:27:47 hostname kernel: IPTables-Dropped: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00000 SRC=255.255.255.1 DST=10.0.0.1 LEN=56 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=10 ID=36830 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=490000 DPT=80 WINDOW=15500 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 MARK=0x32
... Sep  1 09:27:47 hostname kernel: IPTables-Dropped: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00000 SRC=255.255.255.1 DST=10.0.0.1 LEN=56 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=10 ID=36830 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=490000 DPT=80 WINDOW=15500 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 MARK=0x32
... Sep  1 09:27:47 hostname kernel: IPTables-Dropped: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00000 SRC=255.255.255.2 DST=10.0.0.1 LEN=56 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=10 ID=36830 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=490000 DPT=80 WINDOW=15500 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 MARK=0x32""".splitlines()
>>> lstset = {l.split()[9].replace('SRC=','') for l in content}
>>> print('\n'.join(lstset))
255.255.255.1
255.255.255.2
```

---

But a better way (and slower one) would be to use regex. Example -

```
import re
reqset = {re.search('SRC=(\S+)',l).group(1) for l in content}
print('\n'.join(reqset))
```

Demo -

```
>>> reqset = {re.search('SRC=(\S+)',l).group(1) for l in content}
>>> print('\n'.join(reqset))
255.255.255.1
255.255.255.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have a string that contains just one line of your input, you can do

```
parts = line.split()
ip = parts[9][4:]
```

Sample Output:
    255.255.255.1

You may want to do some suitable range checking on those lists, of course!

([live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/11ccec748dc6c085))

---

[string.split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) will produce a list of strings from a single string, splitting by a delimiter of your choice (space, by default).
You can then index that list to pick the one that corresponds to `SRC=xx.xx.xx.xx`, and use [string slicing](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) to return the substring that consists of just the IP address.

A more robust approach might be to use regular expressions to match against the `SRC=xx.xx.xx.xx` line and extract the IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Finally followed this approach:

```
import sys
import os
import re

for line in open("iptables.log","r"):

 list = line.strip().split(" ")
 if re.search("SRC=", line):

  ip = list[10].strip().split("=")
  print ip[1]
```